# the phonegap browser does not support webvr with iframe

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap, webvr

I have a problem with phonegap, in my Android project I have an iframe pointing to a vr tour hosted on my website, but when I enter vr mode the tour replies that webvr is not supported, but on Android the default browser it's chrome and is supported by webvr. I looked for a solution today, but I only found crosswalk for Cordova, but this does not solve my problem because the problem is in the browser that cordova uses with iframes.

Precisely that webgl works correctly, I do not know if it can help.

thanks to all and a good day.

Comment: Have you tried using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` to open the webvr site?  I can't remember what browser it uses, but if it is the default browser and your default browser is chrome then it should work.

Comment: @BShaps Yes, I tried with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and it works fine. I also thought about using inappbrowser but the window should open in an iframe to give me the possibility to work with other elements on it. Thank you .